# Division of a raster into multiple rasters by its value

Tags: qgis, raster, splitting, scp

After the supervised classification of the original raster I want to divide/split the classified raster into multiple rasters by its classes. My aim is to use the single classes as polygons and calculate their areas.

Is there any tool I can use in QGIS?

Comment: You can get polygons directly. Search for "polygonize".

Comment: I know. But I want to polygonize the raster and get multiple vector layers based on the classes (values) in the raster. Do you know how?

Comment: Polygonize and split the polygons into separate layers by the attribute where the original raster values are stored.

Comment: All right. So, there is no chance to polygonize the raster into many vector layers at the same time. I need to polygonize the raster first and then, I split the vector layer to separate layers, right?

Comment: Yes. For me the difference is not so big. For many use cases it is not necessary to split the vector data at all. Layer can be filtered or classified on-the-fly.